# F# noob - map & reduce words

Tags: f#, mapping

I am trying F# and trying to make a map reduce for a list of words to a word, count.

Here's what I have so far,

```
let data1 = ["Hello"; "Hello"; "How"; "How"; "how"; "are"]

let map = data1 |> List.map (fun x -> (x, 1))
printfn "%A" map
```

which gives the following output:

```
val map : (string * int) list =
  [("Hello", 1); ("Hello", 1); ("How", 1); ("How", 1); ("how", 1); ("are", 1)]
```

but

```
    let reduce = ...???
```

Now I am confused to how design a reduce function so that it has the word, count pair list. Any suggestions? I appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's a built-in function for that:

```
data1 |> Seq.countBy id
```

which will give you a sequence of tuples:

```
val it : seq<string * int> =
    seq [("Hello", 2); ("How", 2); ("how", 1); ("are", 1)]
```

The `id` function is another built-in function that takes a value and returns the same value, so in this case it means that you count by the strings themselves.

---

If you rather want a `list` than a `seq`, you can use `Seq.toList`:

```
> data1 |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.toList;;
val it : (string * int) list =
  [("Hello", 2); ("How", 2); ("how", 1); ("are", 1)]
```

If you want a `map`, this is also easy:

```
> data1 |> Seq.countBy id |> Map.ofSeq;;
val it : Map<string,int> =
  map [("Hello", 2); ("How", 2); ("are", 1); ("how", 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the `map` list. It's simpler to directly put the list into an associative map:

```
let reduce x =
        x |> List.fold (fun m x -> match Map.tryFind x m with
                                   | None -> Map.add x 1 m
                                   | Some c -> Map.add x (c+1) m)
                       Map.empty
```

Let's try it in the interpreter:

```
> reduce data1
val it : Map<string,int> = map [("Hello", 2); ("How", 2); ("are", 1); ("how", 1)]
```

There is a good explanation of how to use the reducing function `fold` [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists#List.fold_and_List.foldBack), and a good explanation of how to use the associative map data structure `Map<'Key,'T>` [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Sets_and_Maps#Maps).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively inefficient but easy to understand solution:

```
data1 |> Seq.groupBy id |> Seq.map (fun (a,b) -> a,Seq.length b)
```

essentially, do the grouping and then see how many elements are in each group.

@ildjarn pointed out an improvement, which is probably the most efficient and also even simpler:

```
data1 |> Seq.countBy id
```

Comment: Why not `Seq.countBy id`?

Comment: @ildjarn - didn't think of that, but it is much better